# C++11 Thread-safe initialization of function-local static const objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static, initialization

This question has been asked in a C++98 context, and answered in that context, but nothing was clearly stated about C++11

```
const some_type& create_const_thingy()
{
    lock my_lock(some_mutex);
    static const some_type the_const_thingy;
    return the_const_thingy;
}

void use_const_thingy()
{
    static const some_type& the_const_thingy = create_const_thingy();

    // use the_const_thingy
}
```

Would this initialization pattern ensure that:

1. No race condition occurs
2. `create_const_thingy` is called only once
3. Is this still valid if we remove the mutex lock?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since C++11 all static local variables are guaranteed to be initialized only once in a thread-safe manner.

As per [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables):

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local
>   variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar
>   behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with `std::call_once`).
>   Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the
>   double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for
>   already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean
>   comparison.

So, for your questions:

1. yes
2. yes
3. yes