# Why does this char array need to be static?

Tags: c++

```
const char * u8_to_bstr(const uint8_t & u8) {
    static char s[9];   // space for 8-char string
    s[8] = 0;           // terminate string
    char * sp = s;
    for (uint8_t xbit = 0b10000000; xbit > 0; xbit >>= 1) {
        cout << s << endl;
        *(sp++) = ((u8 & xbit) == xbit) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    return s;
}
```

I encountered this piece of code studying that converts a uint8 to a string representing its binary. My question is, why do we need the static qualifier for static char s[9]? When I remove the static qualifier I get some very strange behavior but I don't understand why.

Comment: Local variables cease to exist when the function exits, and static variables persist.  The function is returning a pointer to the static variable.  If the variable isn't static, then the returned pointer will point at garbage.

Comment: I wonder why would it need to take `uint8_t` by const reference, lol

Comment: This use of `static` is a sign of poor API design. There are better ways to “keep a pointer valid”, including (but not limited to) (a) accepting an “output” pointer argument or (b) dynamic allocation with ownership transfer (i.e. `return`ing a `std::unique_ptr`). The only meaningful use of `static` local variables I can think of is with `const` types (also pointing at a `const` or at something thread-safe). That benefits from C++’s nice “initialize once, in a thread-safe way” guarantee and follows the “spherical code” idea. The way `static` is used here is quite ugly and ”anti-thread-safe”.

Comment: More on [thread-safe initialization of `static const` local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40579252/8584929). A `static` local variable that doesn’t benefit from this property (i.e. is _not_ `const` and/or doesn’t point at something `const` / thread-safe) is usually a suboptimal (and/or wrong, in some sense) use of `static` local variables.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek What is the "spherical code" idea?

Comment: @NathanPierson Sadly I can’t find the original blog(s) any more and the term *spherical code* has been (it seems) completely taken over by algebra and physics. Originally *spherical code* (in software engineering) referred to the idea of minimizing the interface “size” (and exposure of implementation internals in general). *Spherical* was a reference to the way of exposing the smallest [interface] surface area per [implementation] volume contained within. In the code snippet above, the exposure of a “thread-unsafe” internal data structure goes against the principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function returns `s`, which is declared on the stack of this function. Were it not static, it would go out of scope, effectively disappear, once the function returns because all the storage on the stack is made available for reuse once a function returns. By making it static, it’s forced to have a persistent address in memory. However, it’s still bad design - if you call this function from multiple threads, they’ll fight with each other for use of the static memory space.

Comment: Yes. Using `static` is a hacky way to avoid dynamic allocation, which works correctly only in a single-threaded enviroment. And even then, it can easily lead to bugs such as `const char* a = u8_to_bstr(num1); const char* b = u8_to_bstr(num2);` (`a` points to the same string as `b`, which is very unexpected for the caller). I'd say, it's a bad practice. It could at least accept a pointer to the buffer, like `sprintf` for example

Comment: You should also zero the array completely, when it is printed for every bit. Now, at least the garbage is upper bounded to 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @VorpalSword offered in their answer, *it doesn't have to be static.* Instead you could dynamically allocate the array. This dynamically allocated memory will remain valid after `u8_to_bstr` exits.

```
const char * u8_to_bstr(const uint8_t & u8) {
    const char *s = new char[9];   // space for 8-char string
    s[8] = 0;           // terminate string
    char *sp = s;
    for (uint8_t xbit = 0b10000000; xbit > 0; xbit >>= 1) {
        cout << s << endl;
        *(sp++) = ((u8 & xbit) == xbit) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    return s;
}
```

It's a remarkably small change to your code, but it does have implications for how your program works, and you do have to remember later to free up this memory.

```
delete[] variable_holding_results_of_u8_to_bstr;
```

This is a simple view os storing your data in memory so that it will remain usable after `u8_to_bstr` finishes its work without using `static`. It is by no means the only way or the best way.

In good practice, you'd make use of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector` rather than manually allocating and deleting arrays.  Here is a quick view of your code translated to use these tools. Please note I've added a `print_vec` helper function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using std::vector;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::make_unique;

void print_vec(unique_ptr<vector<char>> const& v);
unique_ptr<vector<char>> u8_to_bstr(const uint8_t & u8);

int main() {
    auto r = u8_to_bstr(45);

    print_vec(r);
}

void print_vec(unique_ptr<vector<char>> const& v) {
    for (auto ch : *v) {
        std::cout << ch;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

unique_ptr<vector<char>> u8_to_bstr(const uint8_t & u8) {
    auto s = make_unique<vector<char>>(9, '\0');
    auto sp = s->begin();

    for (uint8_t xbit = 0b10000000; xbit > 0; xbit >>= 1) {
        print_vec(s);

        *(sp++) = ((u8 & xbit) == xbit) ? '1' : '0';
    }

    return s;
}
```

You will almost certainly need to compile this specifying the C++14 or C++17 standards. If you wish to research the types and functions introduced, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a good site, and will tell you what C++ standards types/fucntions were introduced in.

Comment: Using `new`/`delete` in your code is just as bad practice as using `static`. If you want to remove the `static` by using dynamically allocated memory, I would recommend `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Comment: Given the OP's demonstrated level of knowledge, this felt like a good introduction.

Comment: Yes, I understand that your code is a simple way to show that the array can be stored "somhere else". I just think it is also important to tell new c++ users that outside of coding exercises, `new`/`delete` should only be used to implement `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.